# Duvidas no uso do Contains com o Regex no C#

Tags: c#, regex

Gostaria de usar em um código no C# o método `Contains` , mas ao invés de passar uma `string` literal, ou seja, uma palavra específica, passar um padrão ou uma expressão regular como parâmetro. Por exemplo:
Ao invés de passar:

```
bool nomeDaVariavel.Contains("#NUSAPRO");
```

passar algo como:

```
String verifica = @"^#/[A-Z]{1,7}";
//Padrão que captura qualquer String 
//que comece com o "#", 
//seguido de um a sete caracteres de A a Z em caixa grande

bool nomeDaVariavel.Contains(verifica);
```

Com certeza a sintaxe esta errada, mas é só para ter uma idéia do que pretendo.

Se puderem ajudar, fico grato.

Comment: A sua intenção é reescrever o método String.Contains() para toda a aplicação, ou apenas ter uma chamada de um método específico para não precisar usar a API Regex diretamente?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar a classe `Regex` para aplicar a expressão regular nas strings que você quer comparar. O código abaixo mostra um exemplo de como isso pode ser feito.

```
String verifica = @"^#[A-Z]{1,7}";
Regex verificaRegex = new Regex(verifica);
var negativos = new string[] { "ABCDEFG", "#aBCDEFG", "# ABCDEFg", "#aBCDEFG", "#1BCDEFG" };
var positivos = new string[] { "#ABCDEFG", "#ABCDEFG1", "#ABCDEFGHIJKL", "#ABCDEFG abc" };

Console.WriteLine("Negativos:");
foreach (var neg in negativos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(verificaRegex.IsMatch(neg));
}

Console.WriteLine("Positivos:");
foreach (var pos in positivos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(verificaRegex.IsMatch(pos));
}
```

Comment: Carlos boa noite.No caso estes "negativos" seriam uma proteção aos dados recebidos?Pq a própria String , por ser case sensitive,verifica já bloquearia algum caracter que não fosse maiúsculo e com espaço entre ou antes dele, etc certo?

Comment: Carlos boa noite.No caso estes "negativos" seriam uma proteção aos dados recebidos ou a string de entrada a ser analizada?Pq a própria String , por ser case sensitive,verifica já bloquearia algum caracter que não fosse maiúsculo e com espaço entre ou antes dele, etc certo?

Comment: A lista de casos "positivos" e "negativos" são somente algumas strings que usei para testar a expressão regular. O que faz uma string que comece com `#a` ser considerada negativa (i.e., não *match*), é a sua expressão regular. Como você especificou que quer apenas os caracteres `A-Z`, então a expressão só irá fazer o *match*  com caracteres maiúsculos. Se você quiser também incluir os minúsculos, você pode trocar a expressão por `$#[A-Za-z]{1,7}`.